# button.click() issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on a project and I just created a form, also I used Bootstrap grids to structure the design, codes are as follows:

```
<div class="container well" id="block1">
<h4 style="text-align:center">Stock Market Search</h4>
  <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label  for="stock" class="col-sm-3">Enter Stock Ticker Symbol:*</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" placeholder="e.g. AAPL" name="stockName"> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Get Quote</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Clear</button>
          </div>
      </div> 
 </form>
 </div>
```

But when I tried to get the data from www.google.com the button.click() just didn't work. My jQuery codes are as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#block1 .glyphicon-search", function(){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://www.google.com',
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
     }
 })
    })
});
```

What could be the possible issue? I guess it's something wrong with iQuery and Bootstrap conflicts. But could anyone help?
(P.S. The cross domain issue is solved by installing extensions on Chrome so that is not the problem here.)

Comment: First of all you target the icon and not the whole button. Second you cannot make AJAX requests to different domains unless the specifically allow it. Google does not. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I solved the cross domain issues by installing extensions on chrome so that's not the point. Also when I change the class to "button" no operations also.

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** : jquery `on` is a live listener and there is no need to wrap it inside DOM ready:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#block1 .glyphicon-search", function(){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://www.google.com',
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
     }
 })
})
```

**Second:** Ajax request can not point to external domains (seems to be solved by installing extension).

**Third:** The click listener is on the span not on the button.

**Fourth:** The span is empty (Perhaps by mistake) so has zero width  (non-clickable)!

**Fifth**: prevent the form from submitting by pressing the button or completely remove the form tag.

and finally make sure that you dont have multiple `#block1` id in your page so the selector will work only on the first occurance.

Comment: The problem is solved. When I delete <form> tags, it works, seems like strange but the issue is solved. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the solution. I have updated the answer to cover your own solution too